# Android HTTP header attachment filename ignored

Tags: android, http, header, filenames, tablet

I maintain a store which allows people to download mp3s they have purchased. The URL they enter to download the mp3 is of the form:

```
http://domainName/download.php?a=123&b=456
```

Here is a typical header which my php program sends to the browser (captured with Fiddler):

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Length: 3011430
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="AIR FOR PIPES.MP3";
```

On an Android tablet (ASUS Transformer), either pre 4.0 or post 4.0, the downloaded file is called "download.php", not "AIR FOR PIPES.MP3". In other words the browser ignores the attachment filename. At least the song plays fine even with the .php suffix! Curiously on a Samsung Charge Android 2.3.6 phone the filename is "AIR_FOR_PIPES.MP3" (the phone added the underscores which is fine). On windows, this code works fine on IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Only the tablet is giving me grief with the filename.

Other sites have suggested I must have no space after the ";" and mp3 must be in caps - neither is the solution. Other information suggests this is a known bug with POST but as you can see I am doing only GET. I have also tried specifying "application/octet-stream" but it makes no diff.

Is there some tablet setting that is causing the file to initially be called "Untitled" but ultimately stored as "download.php"? (My tablet is encrypted - not sure if that is relevant.)

EDIT/ANSWER: (forum won't let me answer my own question)
Apparently the tablet will not tolerate spaces in the attached filename. I removed them and the filename was recorded correctly as AIRFORPIPES.MP3.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers on your Transformer (e.g. firefox, the full chrome, etc...) to see if it's something in that particular Android version, or something with the stock browser in android?

Comment: Yes, I tried Chrome Beta which is now available for ICS. It provide the same result as the stock browser. I can try Firefox on the tablet later today...

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this is ultimately a browser implementation issue. ([Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx)'s a post describing IE's issues with that header). Lots of manufacturers customize the browser, so it wouldn't be shocking to see differences in implementation between Android devices. Marc B's suggestion of trying different browsers is a good one. I doubt you will find a setting to fix this unfortunately.

Comment: I was indeed amazed it worked on my boss's Droid phone when it failed on my tablet under ICS.

Answer (score 0):

The forum will now let me answer my own question. As mentioned above in my EDIT the Android tablet will not accept spaces in the filename, nor will it accept underscores, even thought the Droid phone converts the spaces to underscores! The Android tablet converts AIR%20FOR%20PIPES to AIR FOR PIPES but the Droid phone converts it to AIR 20FOR 20PIPES so really the generic solution is remove spaces from the filename before sending the header.